# Count possible combinations of factors of number N, excluding 1 and itself, which on multiplication yield N

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, number-theory

Given a number `N`, find the number of combinations of its factors (excluding 1 and N), which on multiplication yield N. Eg:

```
N = 12
answer = 3
relevant factors : 2,3,4,6
combinations : {2,6},{3,4},{2,2,3}.
```

To solve this, I came up with the following logic, which is adequate for nearly all cases, but undercounts in a few cases. Please help me in understanding what I am missing. My Logic:

I divide the set of combinations into "primary" and "secondary". The ones which occur as a direct combination of the factors are primary. In the above example, `{2,6}` and `{3,4}` are primary. Those which come up as a result of further breaking one of the original factors is secondary. Eg: `{2,2,3}` can be called a combination of 2 with breakdown of 6 into `{2,3}` or of 3 with breakdown of 4 into `{2,2}`.
For every number, I first find the number of primary factors, then the number of secondary factors by recursively repeating the process for the largest relevant factor. Eg:

```
f(32) = 2 + f(16);
f(16) = 2 + f(8);
f(8) = 1 + f(4);
f(4) = 1;
Thus, f(32) = 6.
```

In the above, the primary combinations of 32 are {2,16} and {4,8}. Hence the 2 in the first step. This explains rest of the steps too.

The problem is, this solution fails for a few values of N. Eg: It returns 8 for 90, but the correct answer is 10. It returns 16 for 180, but the correct answer is 25. For 60, correct is 10, but mine is 9.

Please help me.

Comment: The reason I may be missing is since I am only using the largest factor for recursion. However, I thought that doing so is sufficient, since all we are reporting here ultimately is a combo of prime factors, and all such unique combos can be captured using the largest factor alone.

Comment: what are your 8 combinations for 90, and what are the 10 that are supposedly correct? I only get five combinations for 90. Note that there are 10 *divisors* of 90 (and 8 *proper* divisors), but your are not counting divisors. For example 3 and 4 are divisors of 12, but you didn't count (3,4) as being different than (4,3). Also you might want to look at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) on divisors.

Comment: I don't think your theory "... all such unique combos can be captured using the largest factor alone ..." is correct in general.

Comment: It would help a lot if you spell out the _actual_ `6` combinations of factors of `32`.

Comment: These are called [multiplicative partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition), there are indeed ten distinct partitions for 90. Your definitions of "primary" or "secondary" combinations and the logic for the "f" function are a bit hard to follow. You are close with the largest factor logic: the number of partitions of `n` is the sum, over all proper factors `x`, of (factorizations where `x` is the largest factor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the guidance from the comment from @kcsquared, I was able to understand how exactly to approach this problem.

We simply need to iterate over all divisors of n. Doing so will give what I was referring in the question as "primary combos". In order to find multiplicative partitions using recursion, I should recursively find divisors of the larger of the two divisors found in the ongoing iteration, but this time with a modification. Rather than starting search from 2, one should start from the smaller divisor from the iteration. This is to prevent over-counting. Below is my code.

```
def divisors(s,l):
    tot = 0
    for i in range(s,l):
        if n%i == 0 and n//i >= i: #Preventing counting same combo again, and early stopping.
            tot += 1
            if n//i > 0:
                tot += divisors(i,n//i)
    return tot
n = 60
print(divisors(2,n))
```

This is giving the correct answer. The implementation I came up with earlier was much more complex, and was unable to recurse for anything but the largest factor. If I do that for n = 60, I will not be able to count {3,4,5}, as:

```
On partitioning 60, I get: 2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30.
```

Now, If I further divide 30, then 15 then 5, I will not get 4 anywhere, since 4 is not a factor of any of these. Hence, 4 will only be counted once in the first step, as part of {4,15}, but never as {3,4,5}.

With the new approach, I will also be able to divide 20 (20*3 = 60), which will count the occurrence of 3 along with 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a **prime factorization** of `N` first and then compute the number (probably using combinatorics) from the exponents (above 1) of primes ...

For example:

```
x^1                                       // 1 options
x^2 = x*x                                 // 2 options
x^3 = x^2*x = x*x*x                       // 3 options
x^4 = x^3*x = x^2*x^2 = x^2*x*x = x*x*x*x // 5 options
x^5 = x^4*x = x^3*x^2 = x^3*x*x*
    = x^2*x^2*x = x^2*x*x*x = x*x*x*x*x   // 7 options
x^6 = x^5*x = x^4*x^2 = x^4*x*x
    = x^3*x^3 = x^3*x^2*x = x^3*x*x*x
    = x^2*x^2*x^2 = x^2*x^2*x*x
    = x^2*x*x*x*x = x*x*x*x*x*x           // 11 options
...

2^2 * 3^1 = 12
options:      2  +  1  = 3 
combinations: 3: {2,6},{3,4},{2,2,3}

2^2 * 3^1 * 5^1 = 60
options:      2  +  1  +  1 = 4 options
combinations: 9: {12,5},{2,6,5},{3,4,5},{2,2,3,5},{6,10},{3,20},{2,2,15},{4,15},{2,30}
```

However I am **not sure** what the formulas are for `options = f(exponent)` and `combinations = f(sum_of_options)` it most certainly involves combinatorics and or recursive calculations from one less exponent. I am too lazy to check it for now...

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question asked.

Comment: @onyambu yes it needs to add the math ... its just a start point. The OP is not doing prime decomposition but more like weird recursive like brute force so I assume/guess that some failed cases are due to accounting something more than once which prime decomposition like this will not. The counting algo is the same however it just does not divide anymore as the number of options can be computed directly from prime decomposition